# How to resolve problems with SignalR after IIS publish?

Tags: c#, websocket, signalr, blazor-server-side, iis-10

I have some problem with blazor server and signalr on IIS.
When i trying to start the application from iis, i get the following error

[error when start page on iis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRYW1.png)

I've published my solution .NET Core 3.1 (blazor server + SignalR) on IIS version 10.0.
I've activated Websocket Protocol for IIS from Server Manger -> Rules And Features.
I've tried on Debug Mode and i'didn't find any errors, but from IIS it give an error "Error: connnection disconnecdet with error: Error server time elapsed... ":

How I can configure IIS for Websocket Protocol and SignalR? In my case I have tried to set HttTransportType for all Hubs of the SignalR

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client" Version="5.0.16" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core" Version="1.1.0" />
```

[hhttpTransport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tn6V.png)

On IIS -> ApplicationPool-> Recycling Condition is flag to false.

Comment: Please add the content of the errors to the question itself. Please don't use off-site resources as links.

Comment: There are quite a few logging options you should now enable to see what is exactly wrong, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-3.1